# Get size of UIView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiview, xamarin.ios

I have a `UIView` and some `Buttons` on a Xamarin `Page`, and I need to find the Width and Height of the `UIView` not the `Frame`.

Are there any ways to solve this?

Comment: Get frame and from the frame you can get the size.

Comment: But isn't the `Frame` the whole `Page`?

Comment: Each view has its own frame

Comment: the frame of a `UIView` contains its x, y, width and height

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that Each View has it's own Frame. What is the difference between Height and Width in Frame and Bounds if any?

Comment: @LasseMadsen frame / bounds have the same height and width. Frames x / y are where in the parent view the current view is positioned. Bounds x / y will always be 0, 0 to denote the starting point of the view

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int width = self.view.frame.size.width
int height = self.view.frame.size.height
```

So when you get the frame you can get the width and the height.

Comment: But isn't `Frame` the whole `Frame` for the `Page`?

Comment: @LasseMadsen as you have already been told, no. Each element on the screen is a subclass of `UIView`. Each viewController has a `UIView` that covers the whole screen. You then add subclasses of `UIView` on top of this. Each have their own property called `frame`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the view's size:

```
float viewWidth = view.Frame.Width;
float viewHeight = view.Frame.Height;
```

If you want to get the whole page's size:

```
float screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
float screenHeight = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

Hope it can help you.